# Printing Common Values of Two Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a java project and need to print common values between two arrays.

I have printed both arrays in their sorted order before hand and they both look good (containing all values they should). However, when I follow the simplest of algorithms (see below) I do not find all the common values even though I can manually see in the print out of the two arrays without comparison that there should be more values printed after executing the below:

```
        for(int i=0; i<fibList.size(); i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<primeList.size(); j++)
            {
                if(fibList.get(i) == primeList.get(j))
                {
                    System.out.print(" " + fibList.get(i));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Please let me know what you think. Hopefully this is just a simple error.

Comment: What do you have in your lists? `Integer` objects or what?

Comment: is this homework? also, if the lists are made up of strings, you might want to try .equals() instead of ==

Comment: are they arrays of objects?  if so == won't work, use fibList.get(i).equals(primeList.get(j))

Comment: the issue was the integers being objects instead of primitives. .equals was necessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you want to:

Change:

```
if(fibList.get(i) == primeList.get(j))
```

To:

```
if(fibList.get(i).equals(primeList.get(j)))
```

Answer (score 4):

`if(fibList.get(i).equals(primeList.get(j)))` could be used.

Answer (score 4):

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>(fibList);
result.retainAll(primeList);
for (Integer i : result) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Awesome mahn, thanks for letting me know about retainAll(). +1